# output doesn't go past enter first number. after I enter the first number (or x) it doesn't go on to the next line

Tags: python, input, sublimetext3

```
def addNumber(fNum, lNum):
    sumNum = fNum + lNum
    return sumNum

x = int(input('enter first number \n'))
print(x)
y = int(input('enter last number \n'))

print(addNumber(x,y))
```

output is

```
enter first number 10
20
```

no matter what I enter for my output nothing happens doesn't move to the next line of my program

Comment: I know this is a basic question but I have looked all over and everything I see says this should be just fine to have the user enter input. But it's not the output just stops and I can't get it to progress through the program.

Comment: This works fine for me.  Are you seeing any error output?

Comment: Works fine on my end as well.

Comment: I just don't know why it's not working. I run other code in the same file just fine

Comment: There are no output errors

Comment: I'm also new at StackOverFlow so I apologize for the poor formatting

Comment: Since you mentioned a formatting of your question - check the indentation! The code sample you provided has no indentation, so the addNumber definition is not correct.

Comment: Thanks for that, in my actual code the indenting was correct. I put it in a different file tried it again and it's till not going to the next line of code. This is so simple it's frustrating that I can't get it to work.

Comment: So I ran this code in Notepad++ and it ran fine. What is strange is I can run other code just fine in Sublime but for some reason when I use this user input command it simple fails. Any ideas on how to fix my sublime IDE or what could be causing this would be appreciated.

Comment: @OdatNurd thanks for that comment, that was the problem. Instead of fixing Sublime I decided to just use Notepad++ instead. Thanks again for that help.